# Selecting OpenCL CPU platform in Compute.scala

Tags: scala, opencl, cpu, lwjgl, pocl

I installed 3 different OpenCL runtimes on my laptop:

- NVIDIA CUDA OpenCL on GPU
- Intel OpenCL SDK on CPU
- POCL (also on CPU)

As a result, here is a part of the result of `clinfo`:

```
$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               3
Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
Platform Vendor                                 The pocl project
Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 pocl 1.1 None+Asserts, LLVM 6.0.0, SPIR, SLEEF, DISTRO, POCL_DEBUG
...
Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL
Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 LINUX
...
Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 9.0.282
```

Now I want to use the [Compute.scala Scala library](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Compute.scala/) to perform NDArray computations on GPU and CPU (based on the LWJGL library.

The device type is selected using the following import line at the beginning of the program:

```
import com.thoughtworks.compute.gpu._ // for GPU
// OR
import com.thoughtworks.compute.cpu._ // for CPU
```

After a quick test, my code runs fine with both device types. However, how am I supposed to know WHICH platform is running when choosing CPU? Is it the Intel OpenCL platform, or POCL?

By looking at the code of the library, I suspect it just picks the first CPU platform in the platform list.

- line `with OpenCL.UseAllCpuDevices` (https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Compute.scala/blob/742d595e5eb56f4051edfc310f64e0f9dbab5ac1/cpu/src/main/scala/com/thoughtworks/compute/cpu.scala#L109)
- line `platformIds.collectFirst { ...` (https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Compute.scala/blob/742d595e5eb56f4051edfc310f64e0f9dbab5ac1/OpenCL/src/main/scala/com/thoughtworks/compute/OpenCL.scala#L363)

So my questions are:

- How do I know which CPU platform is being used?
- How can I select the platform I want to use in Compute.scala?
- Maybe it is necessary to "disable" one of the platforms. If it's the case, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick-and-dirty way to switch between platforms: I simply rename the ICD file in `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/` to "disable" it, so that only the platform I want is detected (can be checked with `clinfo`).

For example `$ sudo mv /etc/OpenCL/vendors/pocl.icd /etc/OpenCL/vendors/pocl.icd_` to use intel64 (the other available CPU platform) instead of pocl, and vice-versa for using pocl instead of intel64.

If someone has a more clean and programmatic way to solve this, their are welcome!